# Application won't exit before Diagnostics.Process.Start() finishes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, excel, vba

I have an application that opens an Excel .xlsm file. The Excel file has a bunch of long-running code in Auto_Open() that can take several minutes to complete.

Currently, I open the excel file and while the macro is still running I exit my application. The main window closes but I can see MyApp.exe running in the task manager until the macros finish, at which point the MyApp.exe process ends.

```
    private void btnOpenExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(excelFilePath);
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
        //Also tried this.Close();
    }
```

I would like to be able to open the Excel file and then exit my application without having to wait for the Excel macros to finish. Is this possible?

Comment: Please show your code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterDuniho done. Hopefully that helps you.

Comment: Try System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()

Comment: This is odd; I have never seen `Process.Start` behave this way.  My own app exports Excel documents and launches them using `Process.Start`, and the app shuts down cleanly while Excel is still open.  Does your app only wait until the macros are done executing, or until Excel exits?

Comment: @MikeStrobel The process exits once the macros have finished executing. Excel can remain open.

Comment: @JoeBauer Were these macros kicked off in Excel, or did you start them programmatically from your app using the Office interop library?

Comment: @MikeStrobel they were started in Excel. The logic is in Auto_Open() so it runs as soon as the workbook is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fair amount of experimentation and research, I know what is going on. It's an unfortunate side-effect of Excel's implementation and the way the native Windows function `ShellExecuteEx` (which `System.Diagnostics.Process` uses) works. In particular, Excel will not acknowledge completion of the DDE command to `ShellExecuteEx` until the `auto_run` macro has completed, and when called in the way the `Process` class uses it `ShellExecuteEx` will not return until that happens or (very important) until two minutes has passed.

(The documentation says there's a one-minute timeout, but on my Windows 8.1 machine it was two minutes).

I discovered a few work-arounds, none completely elegant but all of which should work okay.

NOTE: all of the code examples below would be placed in the click event handler, except where noted otherwise (i.e. interop declarations).

My preferred work-around is to simply use a separate thread to start the process. This doesn't solve the problem of the process itself remaining. But the rest of the process can shut down, leaving the lone thread to wait on the timeout (or the completion of `auto_open`, whichever comes first):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Process.Start(target));

thread.IsBackground = false;
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

One of the problems that comes up when `ShellExecuteEx` *doesn't* wait is that Windows actually *needs* your STA thread to hang around long enough for it to issue the DDE command to Excel to open the given file. This means that any attempt to bypass the delay in `ShellExecuteEx` runs the risk either of Excel not starting at all, or it not opening the requested file.

That said, if you're willing to accept that risk or mitigate it with longer timeouts (but not necessarily as long as the two-minute timeout Windows imposes), there are a couple of other approaches you can take.

The second approach would be to queue a `Close()` call for later execution. This takes advantage of the fact that `ShellExecuteEx` is still running a message pump, and so even though the `Process.Start()` method hasn't returned, you can still get code to execute in your `Form` subclass. An example of this would be:

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Close();
    }));
Process.Start(target);
```

This delays the `Close()` command for one second, which on my computer was long enough to let `Process` and `ShellExecuteEx` do the work necessary to get Excel running.

NOTE: I did try shorter timeouts and found it unreliable. That is, at 100ms instead of 1000ms, Excel didn't start at all. At 500ms, it started but often would not actually load the workbook. At a full second, it was reliable on my SSD-equipped laptop. I don't actually know where the latency is, but it could be that on a machine with a slower drive, a longer timeout would be needed.

One thing I don't like about the above is that it tears down the application before the `Process.Start()` method has actually returned. While it works, this seems a bit too far past the "kosher/non-kosher" line. :)

So a third option is to bypass the `Process` class altogether and invoke `ShellExecuteEx` directly. Doing it this way, you still need to wait or else Excel won't start up reliably. But you can do the waiting *after* the call to `ShellExecuteEx` completes, and so the application cleanup seems cleaner to me. That is, it's a completely normal program exit, allowing all the usual housekeeping you might want to do.

It's a bit longer due to the interop declarations, but it works well:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();

sei.fMask = ShellExecuteMaskFlags.SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
sei.nShow = ShowCommands.SW_NORMAL;
sei.lpFile = target;

if (!Interop.ShellExecuteEx(sei))
{
    int hr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Exception e = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
    // Throw, display message box, whatever you like here
}

await Task.Delay(100);
Close();
```

where the interop declarations look like this (unused enum values have been omitted):

```
class Interop
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ShellExecuteEx(SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SHELLEXECUTEINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public ShellExecuteMaskFlags fMask;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpVerb;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpParameters;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpDirectory;
    public ShowCommands nShow;
    public IntPtr hInstApp;
    public IntPtr lpIDList;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpClass;
    public IntPtr hkeyClass;
    public uint dwHotKey;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public IntPtr hProcess;

    public SHELLEXECUTEINFO()
    {
        this.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
    }
}

public enum ShowCommands : int
{
    SW_NORMAL = 1,
}

[Flags]
public enum ShellExecuteMaskFlags : uint
{
    SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI = 0x00000400,
}
```

Using this technique, I was able to use a much shorter timeout. 100ms seemed to work reliably, while 10ms did not.

Finally note that if you can change the Excel workbook, you should be able to set up a timer in the `auto_open` routine which then later runs the actual initialization code, letting `auto_open` return immediately. Doing that would negate any need to fiddle with the launching code in your C# program at all. :)

Comment: Excellent answer. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way can be to call Environment.Exit(-1) which terminates the process and gives the underlying operation system the specified exit code.